# Refactoring static mocks in Mockito 3.4

Tags: java, unit-testing, static, mockito, refactoring

I have a Jupiter based UnitTest in a java project where I need to mock some static methods of an external utility. Mockito 3.4 allows for mocking static methods, so no need for PowerMock any more. We all use static mocks by defining them in a `try(){}` block and overwriting methods on those static mocks inside the block. All fine, but things sometimes get annoying when you have to implement a non trivial mocking cascade. Which is *especially* annoying of you have to do that in several test cases inside your test class.

```
class ClassA {
    public static void methodA() { ... }
    public static void methodB() { ... }
}

class ClassB {
    public static void methodA() { ... }
    public static void methodB() { ... }
}

class ClassC {
    public static void methodA() { ... }
    public static void methodB() { ... }
}

class ClassX {
    public int doSomething() {
        // does something using static methods from classes ClassA, ClassB, ClassC
        return 3;
    }
}
```

A test class might (roughly) look like that (please excuse typos and nonsense, this is only meant as a demonstration, this is not working code):

```
@Test
void test_doSomething() {

    int result = 0;
    ClassX classX = new ClassX();

    try (MockedStatic<ClassA> classAMockStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(ClassA.class);
         MockedStatic<ClassB> classBMockStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(ClassB.class);
         MockedStatic<ClassC> classCMockStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(ClassC.class)) {

        // this is a block where static methods get overwritten, also some mocks are created
        // this code does not make sense, it is just to demonstrate the issue of non trivial mocking scenarios
        // situations like this often arise when mocking building patterns for example
        classAMockStatic.when(ClassA::methodA).thenReturn("fooA");
        ClassB classBMock = mock(ClassB.class);
        when(classBMock.methodA()).thenReturn("barA");
        classAMockStatic.when(ClassA::methodB).thenReturn(classBMock);
        ClassC classCMock = mock(ClassC.class);
        when(classCMock.someMethodA()).thenReturn("abc");
        when(classCMock.methodA()).thenReturn("barA");
        classAMockStatic.when(ClassA::methodA).thenReturn(classCMock);
        // and so on and so on, you get the idea

        result = classX.doSomething();
    }

    assertThat(result).equals(3);
}
```

Typically the question arises if this cannot be refactored to implement the mocking cascade only once. And use it in several test cases. I tried that, I was surprised to find that *some* of my overwritten methods worked as expected, but not all. I failed to find a working solution:

// THIS DOES NOT WORK

```
@Test
void test_doSomething() {

    int result = 0;
    ClassX classX = new ClassX();

    try (MockedStatic<ClassA> classAMockStatic = createStaticMockA();
         MockedStatic<ClassB> classBMockStatic = createStaticMockB();
         MockedStatic<ClassC> classCMockStatic = createStaticMockC()) {

        result = classX.doSomething();
    }

    assertThat(result).equals(3);
}

private MockedStatic<ClassA> createStaticMockA() {
    MockedStatic<ClassA> classAMockStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(ClassA.class);

    classAMockStatic.when(ClassA::methodA).thenReturn("fooA");
    ClassB classBMock = mock(ClassB.class);
    when(classBMock.methodA()).thenReturn("barA");
    classAMockStatic.when(ClassA::methodB).thenReturn(classBMock);

    return classAMockStatic;
}

private MockedStatic<ClassB> createStaticMockB() {
    MockedStatic<ClassB> classAMockStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(ClassB.class);
    
    ClassB classBMock = mock(ClassB.class);
    when(classBMock.someMethodA()).thenReturn("aaa");
    when(classBMock.someMethodB()).thenReturn("bbb");
    when(classBMock.methodA()).thenReturn("barA");
    classBMockStatic.when(ClassB::methodA).thenReturn(classBMock);
    return classBMockStatic;
}

private MockedStatic<ClassC> createStaticMockC() {
    MockedStatic<ClassC> classAMockStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(ClassC.class);
    
    ClassC classCMock = mock(ClassC.class);
    when(classCMock.someMethodA()).thenReturn("abc");
    when(classCMock.methodB()).thenReturn("barC");
    classCMockStatic.when(ClassC::methodA).thenReturn(classCMock);
    return classCMockStatic;
}
```

So this looks cleared up, but does not work.

I know that I obviously could just extract the mocking section into a method and call that first in the try block. But that separates the static setup from the mock generation. And it is not as clean as my idea.

Yes, I tried implementing an execution method which accepts a lambda holding the code actually meant to be executed. So that the `try(){}` block gets stowed away into a method, leaving only the call to that method with a lambda in the test case. Works, but is hard to read and to understand. Not a good solution in my experience.

And yes, I also know that one should try to refactor production code so that it is easier to mock it. Sometimes that is simply not possible (read: external dependencies).

So what are my questions here?

1. does anyone have an idea how to achieve a clean, refactored look which actually works?
2. can anyone explain to me why some of the overwritten methods work as expected while others don't? I know, all the examples on the internet demonstrate that you use the straight approach, but the examples are obviously showing trivial situations.
3. is it really true that no one else is annoyed by that situation of have to setup the mock cascade exactly where it confuses? And that you have to reimplement it for each test case?

Comment: It's better to use actual running code rather than pseudocode on Stack Overflow. The problem with pseudocode is that if someone spots an error in it, it's impossible to know whether the problem exists in the original code, or if it's just an issue in the translation. The refactored code above is not equivalent to the first code block, which doesn't do anything with `classBMockStatic`. One possible issue is that the refactored code makes two disconnected mock instances of `ClassB`.

Comment: Another thought: it is always possible to refactor the production code in some way to reduce this problem. The Mockito documentation states: ["do not mock types you don’t own"](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests#dont-mock-a-type-you-dont-own). If you find yourself wanting to mock an external dependency, it is usually better to encapsulate the use of that dependency behind an interface that you do control.

Answer (score 1):

As Tim Moore suggests, if you have:

```
class StaticUtil {
  public static void foo() { ... }
}
```

You can introduce an interface and an implementation to inject into your clients:

```
interface Util {
  void foo();
}

class DefaultUtil {
  public void foo() {
    StaticUtil.foo();
}
```

This makes writing tests simpler as you can just mock `Util` in the normal way.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this is not really an answer to my question though ...